# Setting size of generic array in java?

Tags: arrays, generics, dynamic, size, hashtable

I have a private member which is an array of type generics and in my constructor I have a parameter that is to set the size of this array. How could I set my private array to the size specified by the constructor parameter?

**This is what I have:**

```
private T[] hashTable;

public HashTable(int initSize){
    // set hashTable size here
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires an upcast from `Object[]`.

```
public class HashTable<T> {
    private T[] hashTable;

    public HashTable(int initSize){ // set hashTable size here
        hashTable = (T[]) new Object[initSize];
    }
}
```